# A fair dice is thrown six times and the list of numbers showing up is noted. The probability that among the numbers 1 to 6 only 4 nu...

Tags: probability

Question :

A fair dice is thrown six times and the list of numbers showing up is noted. Now how to find the probability that among the numbers 1 to 6 only 4 numbers appear in the list

Please suggest how to solve such problems on probability this will be of great help to me.

Thanks.

Comment: A hint. Let's make this simpler, and let's say we have fair dice, thrown 3 times and we want to know the number of them when there are only 2 distinct numbers. We know that there will be two numbers, $A$ and $B$, and there are $6*5=30$ such combinations. Now the result can be either AAB, ABA or BAA, hence the total number is $30*3=90$. Since there are $6^3=216$ possible combinations, the probability is $90/216$. Makes sense?

Comment: exactly 4 numbers, or "4 numbers or less" ?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 forms an answer can take:

**Form #1:**
ABCDAA (1 triplet (AAA) and 3 singles(BCD))

**Form #2:**
ABCDAB (2 doubles (AA and BB) and 2 singles (C and D))

> For each form, we will multiply 3 things to count all the
>   possibilities for that form:
>   1. # of ways to choose 4 things from 6
>   2. # of ways to select 2 things from 4 AND satisfy the conditions of the form
>   3. # of ways those 6 things can be arranged

**Calculation for Form #1**
1. 6 Choose 4 = **15**
2. We can choose AA, BB, CC, or DD, so **4**
3. We can arrange 6 things in 6! ways, but we must divide to account for the tripled value, so we have 6!/3! = **120**

15 * 4 * 120 = **7,200 ways for form #1**

**Calculation for Form #2**
1. 6 Choose 4 = **15**
2. 4 Choose 2 = **6**
We can choose AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, or CD, but not BA, CA, DA, CB, DB, and DC because we would be double counting. Remember, we will multiply in step 3 to account for all arrangements, so that will cover these cases.
3. We can arrange 6 things in 6! ways, but we must divide to account for the two doubled values, so we have 6!/(2!*2!) = **180**

15 * 6 * 180 = **16,200 ways for form #2**

So, 7,200 ways for form #1 + 16,200 ways for form #2 = **23,400** ways total to get exactly 4 distinct numbers with 6 rolls of a die.

There are 6^6 = 46,656 possible outcomes for rolling a die 6 times, so the probability for rolling exactly 4 distinct numbers in 6 rolls is **23,400/46,656 = 50.154%**